# Matplotlib colorbar with a histogram

Tags: matplotlib

I made a histogram of array x with each bar color-coded according to the average of another property y in that bin. How can I make an associated colorbar?

```
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=np.min(y), vmax=np.max(y))
cmap = cm.jet
m = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)

fig = plt.figure()
n, bins, patches= plt.hist(x, bins = np.arange(0,max_x) + 0.5)
for i in range(np.size(patches)):
    plt.setp(patches[i],color=m.to_rgba(y[i]))
plt.colorbar(norm=norm,cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

This colorbar returns an error message " No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf)."

Answer (score 0):

Found a way using a "ScalarMappable":

```
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
sm._A = []
plt.colorbar(sm)
```